# CodeIgniter version 2.0 is stable enough to use?

Tags: codeigniter

i want to port my application to CodeIgniter but i am wondering whether i should use their v2.0 or v1.72 (then when they release 2.0, upgrade it).

i have never used a framework before so i don't exactly know what implies when upgrading a framework: what does it mean practically - i just move the folders and it will work? or do i have to change a lot of settings, file structure etc? could someone enlighten me about the upgrade process.

and what would you use: v.1.72 or v2.0?

if i'm using the latest version, is there a good documentation for it somewhere so you can read about how to use the new features: packages, drivers and so on.

thanks

Comment: You can find documentation for it in the user_guide folder. You can download the source at http://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/overview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about some of the changes in 2.0 [here](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/03/codeigniter-2).

I would image the upgrade process should be straightforward as long as you do not use any features that are different/removed such as plugins. Just take your models, controllers, etc and drop them into the 2.0 framework. Then regression test you whole app, fixing any problems as you see them...

Comment: Thanks for the link to my article, but the CI upgrade process is a little more complicated than that. You need to convert all helpers to plugins, rename references to Model to CI_Model and plenty of other shit. Expect an article soon.

Comment: Erf I meant plugins to helpers. I wrote that at about 02:00.

Comment: @Phil, i c u everywhere..on SO...on CI...on your Blog...stop haunting me!

Comment: It's been said before, but I am the hepatitis of CodeIgniter. I am EVERYwhere.

Comment: Here is an article on upgrading, it's actually not that complicated if you don't use the old Validation helper or too many plugins: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0

Comment: @Phil - Thanks for the link! What about the HMVC extension and your CodeIgniter REST sever extension - do you know of any upgrade concerns with those? Will they just work on CI 2.0?

Comment: HMVC has been upgraded to be compatible with 1.7.2 and 2.0. My REST controller works with 1.7.2 if you use 2.2 but REST 2.3 is CI 2.0 only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are selling this app or making something mission critical then of course v1.7.2 is the best choice. That said I have PyroCMS running on v2.0 and since some of my bug-fixes were merged it seems stable enough.

Comment: 2.0 is now more stable than 1.7.x, loads of bugs are fixed and 2.0 is now officially released. When this question and answer came out 2.0 was still in dev.

Answer (score 1):

One should consider time frames for deployment:

- If it is one week, then stick to v1.7.2
- If it is three months, go with v2

Assuming three months is approximately to time for a release to stabilise?